# SwiftUI Detail View not Displaying as Desired in iOS Master/Detail App

Tags: swiftui, master-detail, navigationview

I'm trying to create a Master/Detail app that runs on iOS & iPadOS. When I rotate the app to landscape, it runs as expected on iPadOS; however, on iOS, the Master view overlays the Detail view rather than shrinking the Detail to fit the split screen.  I'm probably missing a modifier on one of the Views, but I can't find the solution.  Any help would be very appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            NavigationView {
                MasterView().navigationBarTitle("Star Wars Characters")
                DetailView()
            }.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct MasterView: View {

    @ObservedObject var dataStore = DataStore()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(sortedPeople) { person in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(person: person)) {
                    PersonView(person: person)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var sortedPeople: [Person] {
        return dataStore.people.sorted {$0.firstName < $1.firstName}
    }
}

struct PersonView: View {
    var person: Person
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Text("\(person.lastName)").font(.headline).fontWeight(.ultraLight)
            Text("\(person.firstName)").font(.subheadline).fontWeight(.light)
        }
        .padding(.leading)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {

    var person = Person()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
            Text(displayText()).font(.title)
        }.padding()
        .navigationBarTitle("")
    }

    func displayText() -> String {
        return person.firstName != "" ? "Hello \(person.name)" : "Click on someone to say hi"
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

[iPadOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yidyq.png)

[iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m13Jj.png)

As pointed out, I understand that this is the *default* behavior.  However, if you look at the Apple's Contact app, it appears you can achieve the *desired* behavior.

[Apple's Contact app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiL4E.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior.
iPhone Landscape == iPad Portrait.
If you tap of the visible area of DetailView MasterView will animate off with drawer like animation.